# MOXy XmlNameTransformer for Multiple Packages

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I'm trying to use MOXy to customize the naming algorithm for XML marshaling and schema generation **for classes across multiple packages**.

I'm following the [Eclipse documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts002.htm) and can get it working for a single class:

```
@XmlNameTransformer(com.example.test.NameGenerator.class)
public class Customer
```

or a single package:

```
@XmlNameTransformer(com.example.test.NameGenerator.class)
package com.example.test;
```

(an external bindings file also works, but again you can only specify package per binding file)

*However*, since I have objects spanned across multiple packages, I don't want to have a define the transformer for every package. Additionally I'd like to do this dynamically (i.e. the individual packages aren't known until runtime).

I've tried defining the transformer at a parent package (`com.example`) but this doesn't work--it looks like it needs to be the exact package where the annotated classes are.

Any ideas?

**Update** - more information

Maybe I should mention that the main reason I'm trying to do this so so I can have control over XML/XSD generation--and most specifically, I want complex types to be uppercase instead of the default lower (without needing to annotate every single class), like

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Test ...
```

should generate:

```
<Test>
...
</Test>
```

instead of

```
<test>
...
</test>
```

From other research I've done, the only way I've found to do this is with an `XmlNameTransformer`. But if there's another way and I'm barking up the wrong tree...definitely let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package level is the biggest scope at which you can specify MOXy/JAXB metadata.  You can use the same implementation of `XmlNameTransformer` but you will need to specify it for each package that you want it applied to.

> However, since I have objects spanned across multiple packages, I
>   don't want to have a define the transformer for every package.
>   Additionally I'd like to do this dynamically (i.e. the individual
>   packages aren't known until runtime).

You can programatically create the object model that corresponds to the external mapping document.  Then you can pass the instance of this when creating the `JAXBContext`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-refresh-example.html

Comment: This is fantastic--thanks! I can't believe I missed MetadataSource as a OXM_METADATA_SOURCE property type. I'll expand on your solution in a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Blaise's answer, here is what my implementation looks like. This accomplishes using a transformer for a dynamic set of packages.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.metadata.MetadataSourceAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.XmlBindings;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xmlmodel.XmlSchema;

public class NameTransformerAdapter extends MetadataSourceAdapter {

    private XmlBindings bindings;

    /**
     * @param packageName Fully qualified package name, like {@code com.example.test}
     */
    public NameTransformerAdapter(String packageName) {
            bindings = new XmlBindings();
            bindings.setPackageName(packageName);
            bindings.setXmlNameTransformer(XmlNameTransformer.class.getName());
            bindings.setXmlSchema(new XmlSchema()); // this is necessary
    }
    @Override
    public XmlBindings getXmlBindings(Map<String, ?> properties, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            return bindings;
    }
}
```

The transformer referenced is pretty simple:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLNameTransformer;

public class XmlNameTransformer implements XMLNameTransformer {

    /** Uses capitalized name of class */
    public String transformTypeName(String name) {
            return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    }
    public String transformElementName(String name) {
            return name;
    }
    public String transformAttributeName(String name) {
            return name;
    }
    public String transformRootElementName(String name) {
            return transformTypeName(name);
    }
}
```

Packages are determined at runtime and are tracked as such:

```
List<MetadataSource> adapters = new ArrayList<MetadataSource>();
adapters.add(new NameTransformerAdapter(packageName));
```

Lastly, a JAXBContext can be obtained using the above adapters:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

private JAXBContext getContext(Class<?>[] classes) throws JAXBException {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, adapters);
    return JAXBContextFactory.createContext(classes, properties);
}
```